# I have not paid my bill to Ability GmbH due to medical tragedy and moved to India what happens

Tags: credit-card, debt, germany, repayment

It will be helpful if I find answer for this. I was working in Germany and there I registered in some dating site which I forgot after I moved to India due to my medical tragedy and now I am in financial debt. I am receiving emails from collecting agency Ability GmbH to pay the annual fee though I unregistered my yearly contract with that site later. I am unable to pay at this situation. They keep adding additional fees for not paying, even though I told them my situation. What will happen if I never pay them?

Comment: The real question is whether Germany has a treaty with India that allows Germans to sue you in Indian courts.

Comment: What they certainly *can* do is sue you in other EU countries (if you ever move back to Europe).

Comment: This seems more like a legal question than a personal finance question.